# Need to extract a set of date rows from a range of 2 date columns in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Year    Holiday     HolidayStart  HolidayEnd
2008    Holiday1    09/09/2008    30/09/2008
2008    Holiday2    01/10/2008    21/10/2008
2008    Holiday3    22/10/2008    12/11/2008
2008    Holiday4    01/12/2008    21/12/2008
2008    Holiday5    02/01/2008    22/01/2008
2008    Holiday6    01/03/2008    21/03/2008
2008    Holiday7    23/03/2008    20/04/2008
2008    Holiday8    27/04/2008    16/05/2008
```

I want to convert it so that I'll have a row for each date, like this

```
Year    Holiday     Dates of the holiday
2008    Holiday1    09/09/2008
2008    Holiday1    10/09/2008
2008    Holiday1    11/09/2008
2008    Holiday1    12/09/2008

2008    Holiday2    01/10/2008
2008    Holiday2    02/10/2008
2008    Holiday2    03/10/2008
2008    Holiday2    04/10/2008
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have additional filter requirements (since there are clearly 22 days in both `Holiday1` and `Holiday2`), but you can approach this by projecting a continuous range of dates covering the entire range and then interpolating the `Holidays` table to it:

```
WITH CTENumbers AS
(
   SELECT 0 AS Number
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Number + 1
   FROM CTENumbers
   WHERE Number < 300
),
DateRanges AS
(
   SELECT
      MIN(HolidayStart) AS MinStart,
      MAX(HolidayStart) AS MaxStart
   FROM Holidays
)
SELECT YEAR, Holiday, DATEADD(dd, cte.Number, dr.MinStart) AS DateOfTheHoliday
   FROM
      CTENumbers cte,
      DateRanges dr,
      Holidays h
WHERE 
   DATEADD(dd, cte.Number, dr.MinStart) 
         BETWEEN h.HolidayStart AND h.HolidayEnd
   AND Holiday IN ('Holiday1', 'Holiday2')
ORDER BY HolidayStart
OPTION( MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d4e9/1)

If you need to do this on a regular basis, I would recommend that you persist the Range of Dates (as projected by the CTE as offset from the Start Date) in a permanent table.

Answer (score 0):

This works, although its a bit backwards to use SQL like this. This first block of code creates some temp tables to demonstrate the solution. The second block is the actual solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #demo (
[year] int ,
holiday nvarchar( 50 ) ,
holidaystart date ,
holidayend date );

INSERT INTO #demo ( [year] ,
                    holiday ,
                    holidaystart ,
                    holidayend )
VALUES
( 2008 ,
  'Holiday1' ,
  '2008-09-09' ,
  '2008-09-30' ) ,
( 2008 ,
  'Holiday2' ,
  '2008-10-01' ,
  '2008-10-21' ) ,
( 2008 ,
  'Holiday3' ,
  '2008-10-22' ,
  '2008-11-12' );

CREATE TABLE #result (
[year] int ,
holiday nvarchar( 50 ) ,
holidaydate date );
```

This is the actual code to give you the data, use the top part first to create the demo data.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER( ORDER BY holidaystart ) rownum ,
       holiday ,
       holidaystart ,
       holidayend ,
       [year]
INTO #foreach_item
  FROM #demo;

DECLARE
   @Iter int = ( SELECT MIN( rownum )
                   FROM #foreach_item );
DECLARE
   @Max int = ( SELECT MAX( rownum )
                  FROM #foreach_item );

WHILE @Iter <= @Max

    BEGIN
        DECLARE
           @First_Day date = DATEADD( dd , -1 , ( SELECT holidaystart
                                                    FROM #foreach_item
                                                    WHERE rownum = @Iter ));
        DECLARE
           @Last_Day date = ( SELECT holidayend
                                FROM #foreach_item
                                WHERE rownum = @Iter );
        DECLARE
           @Holiday nvarchar( 50 ) = ( SELECT holiday
                                         FROM #foreach_item
                                         WHERE rownum = @Iter );
        WHILE @First_Day < @Last_Day
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO #result
                SELECT [year] ,
                       holiday ,
                       DATEADD( dd , 1 , @First_Day )
                  FROM #foreach_item
                  WHERE holiday = @Holiday;
                SET @First_Day = DATEADD( dd , 1 , @First_Day );
            END;
        SET @Iter = @Iter + 1;
    END;

SELECT *
  FROM #result
  ORDER BY holiday;
```